# Git Repo Multiple PRs with Submodules Best Practices

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, pull-request

I have a project with one submodule, the structure looks like this:

```
  project (git repo) 
     |- submodule (git repo)
           |- submodule_file.txt
           |- folder/
           ...
     |- file.txt
     |- another_file.txt
     ...
```

On both repositories there are two branches, `main` which I use for production and `dev` which I use for development.
What I have been doing so far is committing on the `dev` branch and then making a PR to `main` and merging both branches.
This is the process I followed:

1. Push all changes of `project` on branch `dev`
2. Make a pull request and merge `dev` commits into `main` branch
3. Locally change to `main` branch and pull to check everything works as expected
4. Push all changes of `submodule` on branch `dev`
5. Make a pull request and merge `dev` commis into `main` branch
6. Locally change to `main` branch and pull to check everything works as expected

Once I finished, I checked locally the `main` branch and found that there was one in the `submodule` that I haven't commited, it is the Merge Pull Request that I had just made, so I had to commit this change and push to `main` to been able to continue working.

If I run `git log` on `project` on the `main` branch I get this:

```
commit 45jw61p3hf72732icjam7 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Me <email@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 20 09:09:33 2022

    PR to codebase

commit 32f27ufml463h1md7mt91
Merge: aaecbd5 186c169
Author: Me <email@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 20 09:04:50 2022 

    Merge pull request #1 from Me/dev
    
    Dev

commit 186c1694fd7905de324a2 (origin/dev, dev)
Author: Me <email@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Feb 20 08:46:05 2022

    Random commit message
```

I understand that if I make a PR on a submodule, I need to make a  commit on the parent project with the new commit generated from this PR. But is there any way to avoid this? I need to work on both `submodule` and `project` at the same time, and I will be making Pull Requests from their `dev` branches to their `main` branches at the same time, I'm fairly new with Git and I was wondering what would be a best practice here, maybe I should merge first `submodule` and commit the PR on `project` before merging this to `main` or continue as I've been doing so far, what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: "*…if I make a PR on a submodule, I need to make a commit on the parent project with the new commit generated from this PR. But is there any way to avoid this?*" No. Gitlink must be committed to the superproject for the superproject to remember at what commit the submodule must be cloned/updated. No way around that.

Comment: You could try using a "rebase merge" in github to merge the PR in the submodule. I haven't tested it but I would assume if the feature branch is based on the current master, there is no actual rebase happening just normal fast-forwarding. And that results in the commit ID not changing during the merge.